# how to control the string value flows in multiple rows in a table. The Value is separated with comma and having dots along with it

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am generating a PDFdocument with `XSLT`. I am having a string value for one of the columns in the table and the value is a combination of dots and hyphen (eg: `D1234.23, .745, .258, -98`). While displaying the value in the document, the line is ending with comma and dot in one line and the value to the next line.

I tried `Keep-together="always"` and `keep-with-next="always"` properties, but it is not working. Can someone please suggest some other option for this.

```
    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="1"
               number-rows-spanned="1"
               space-before.optimum="8pt"
               border-color="black"
               border-style="solid"
               border-width="0.4pt"
               white-space-collapse="false"
               white-space-treatment="preserve">
    <fo:block space-after.optimum="10pt"></fo:block>
    <fo:block-container overflow="condense"
                        axf:overflow-condense="font-size"
                        font-weight="bold">
        <fo:block text-align="center"
                  space-before.optimum="2pt"
                  axf:text-align-string="center"
                  keep-with-next="always">ABCDEF.TRR, -234, -543, .243, .867, .124, .322, .3123, .1334
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Actual result: 
`ABCDEF.TRR, -234, -543, .243, . 
867, .124, .322, .3123, .1334`

Expected result:
`ABCDEF.TRR, -234, -543, .243, 
.867, .124, .322, .3123, .1334`

Comment: The keep-together attributes are working like "keep this element on one page" or "keep this element with previous/following element on one page". I think you are searching the attribute hyphenate="false" instead of the keep-together. :)

Comment: hyphen is not appended in the actual output. hyphenate="false" property is used to remove the hyphen on line break. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add fo:inline for each value separated by ',' as below, it can fix your issue

```
<fo:block text-align="center" space-before.optimum="2pt" axf:text-align-string="center"
    keep-with-next="always">
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">ABCDEF.TRR</fo:inline>,
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">-234</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">-543</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">.243</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">.867</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">.124</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">.322</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">.3123</fo:inline>, 
    <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">.1334</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```